# How execution of a coroutine resume in main function?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, threadpool, program-entry-point, coroutine

If we use coroutine in main function then, how execution of coroutine resume after delay.
Like in this image, coroutine is in main function and after delay of 2 second code resumes. So I just wanted to know how execution going back to the code after delay. I know about state machine and how coroutine works in android. I am asking about kotlin with main function( Not in android activity ).[image]

Comment: They really work in a similar way, no matter the platform. What is confusing to you in your above code?

Comment: In android there is handler and looper so coroutine can resume task but in simple console application there is no handler and looper so how can coroutine resume itself after delay

Comment: Handler/looper isn't a technique specific to Android - it is simply a thread(s) + queue of tasks. In Java we have executors that do a similar thing. Kotlin coroutines do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how coroutines work in Android I am unsure what is confusing you. Coroutines are non blocking so as soon delay is done print will get executed.

**Global scope** is used to launch top-level coroutines which are operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled prematurely.

Comment: How is coroutine resuming itself in a simple console application as there is no handler and looper.

Comment: There are still threads like in any JVM applications https://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalScope.launch {
   delay(2000)
   print("World)
}
println("Hello")
Thread.sleep(3000)
```

Without going much into the detail of coroutine `suspend/resume` execution using `continuation` or `state-machine`

> how execution of coroutine resume after delay

Because, you are `blocking` the main thread. `Thread.sleep(3000)` blocks the main thread for 3secs. If you remove `Thread.sleep` you can see the difference.

In android it's isn't required, reason being android UI thread runs on `Handler/Looper` concept, which is same as any other thread, only difference being, it always keep the Main/UI thread alive and keep executing the tasks from the `message-queue`.